# What is an isotropic (spherical) covariance matrix?

Tags: terminology, covariance-matrix, definition

Could somebody explain to me in simple terms what an isotropic covariance matrix is? I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 27):

A covariance matrix $\mathbf C$ is called *isotropic*, or *spherical*, if it is proportionate to the identity matrix: $$\mathbf C = \lambda \mathbf I,$$ i.e. it is diagonal and all elements on the diagonal are equal.

---

This definition does not depend on the coordinate system; if we rotate coordinate system with an orthogonal rotation matrix $\mathbf V$, then the covariance matrix will transform into $$\mathbf V^\top \mathbf C \mathbf V = \mathbf V^\top \cdot \lambda \mathbf I \cdot\mathbf V = \mathbf V^\top \mathbf V \cdot \lambda \mathbf I = \lambda \mathbf I,$$ i.e. will stay the same.

Intuitively, isotropic covariance matrix corresponds to a "spherical" data cloud. A sphere remains a sphere after rotation.

Comment: What if the variables can be rotated to get to $\lambda \mathbf I$ covariance matrix?

Comment: @Aksakal See update.

Comment: +1. But curiously, [a completely different definition of "isotropic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form) also applies to $C$ because--as is usual with covariance matrices--it represents a quadratic form on a real vector space.  But in this other sense, the *only* isotropic covariance matrix is the zero matrix!

Comment: @whuber Interesting! I did not remember that there exists a notion of "isotropic" quadratic forms. But reading the definition now, wouldn't any covariance matrix with at least one zero eigenvalue be "isotropic" in that sense?

Comment: You're right--I mis-specified the quantifier.  By definition, an isotropic quadratic form has at least one nonzero isotropic vector (rather than *all* vectors being isotropic).

Answer (score 0):

The covariance is only a function of $|x - x'|$. You can find a definition [there](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf).

Edit: sorry I misread, for matrix, the right answer is amoeba's one.

Comment: The questions asks about covariance *matrix*. Of course a matrix can be seen as a function, but I guess this requires some elaboration for the OP.