# Should I check for autocorrelation in a Bayesian Structural Time Series Model (CausalImpact)?

Tags: bayesian, autocorrelation, structural-equation-modeling, causalimpact, durbin-watson-test

Is it recommended to check for autocorrelation in a Bayesian Structural Time Series model (using CausalImpact)?

If so, could I use the Durbin Watson significance table for models with no intercept to determine the lower and upper bounds for the critical values? [https://www3.nd.edu/~wevans1/econ30331/Durbin_Watson_tables.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ewevans1/econ30331/Durbin_Watson_tables.pdf)

Comment: Is the model likelihood built on the assumption that the model errors (not the original variable) are not autocorrelated? If so, it would be relevant to check that. If the assumption fails, the implications of the estimated model could not be trusted.

Comment: Bayesians don't _test_ for serial correlation, they _model_ it. If you believe autocorrelation to be present (which, in case you're using time series data, it probably is), your likelihood should [accommodate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/396739).

Comment: Thanks both @RichardHardy Do you have any links to examples showing how to accommodate autocorrelation in the likelihood? I am a little hazy on how this would work in practice.

Comment: I do not have links, but the basic logic is to formulate the model in a way that the error term is i.i.d. So if the dependent variable $y_t$ is not i.i.d., then perhaps the error term in $y_t=\varphi_1y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ is, so that you obtain a model with an i.i.d. error term.

Comment: This is fairly old stuff (dating back to [Zellner & Tiao 1964](https://doi.org/10.2307/2283097) if not further), so most textbooks cover it. This includes non-Bayesian ones as well, since the likelihood function is common between both. Just from the top of my head, here's [Martin/Hurn/Davis](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Econometric_Modelling_with_Time_Series/I_W4UCYJhrAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA231).